# Meaning of -b and -p in bash script.sh -b -p directory

Tags: bash

I am downloading miniconda3 and I see the following command in the instruction. What does the `-b` and `-p` mean in this case?

```
/bin/bash miniconda.sh -b -p /conda/installation/path
```

Comment: Check miniconda.sh documentation or sources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoted from [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/silent-mode/):

> -b -- Batch mode with no PATH modifications to ~/.bashrc. Assumes that you agree to the license agreement. Does not edit the .bashrc or .bash_profile files.
>
> -p -- Installation prefix/path.

In case you're wondering, `PATH` designates [path environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)).